# Solving a power series ODE centered at 1.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The power series is $$xy'' + x^{2}y' - 2y = 0$$ I know how to do the power series, but i get stuck on the $ x^2 $, because for the $ x $, i use x = $ (x-1+1) $, but when it's squared i don't know how to do it.

Comment: By the same reasoning, $x^2 = (x-1)^2 +2(x-1) +1$. Just square $(x-1) +1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to find $$y=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i (x-1)^i$$ which satisfies the equation $$xy'' + x^{2}y' - 2y = 0$$ To go back to something more trivial, define $x-1=t$ which makes $$y=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i t^i$$ and the equation $$(t+1)y''+(t^2+2t+1)y'-2y=0$$